# Reading a stream from kafka using spark streaming and assigning a schema to it

Tags: scala, csv, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read a stream from kafka, where the value is a string of comma separated values (representing columns in a dataset)
The objective is to read two such streams and join them.

If I was reading from a file, there is a way to do this by assigning a separator and a schema to the input stream. This is what I am able to do:

```
val stearm_L: DataFrame = spark.readStream
      .option("sep", ";")
      .schema(schema_L)
      .csv("inputFileSteam_L")
```

How I can do the same if I am reading from kafka instead of a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `csv("filename")`, you basically replace that with `format("kafka")`.

There's a page under the Spark Streaming section about Kafka integration for more details.

Regarding getting CSV parsed, see [spark streaming: read CSV string from kafka, write to parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903276/spark-streaming-read-csv-string-from-kafka-write-to-parquet)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, this is what I did. However I am not able any more to split the data and assign schema.

For example, this is what I am able to do:
val stream_L_kafka: DataFrame = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "L_stream")
      .load()

    val stream_L: Dataset[(String, String)] = stream_L_kafka.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)").as[(String, String)]
   
The value is the comma separated string that I want to split and then assign a schema to it

Comment: What difficulties are you having using `map()` to go over the dataframe and split the string of the value column?