# CSV data source does not support binary data type

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to run a spark-streaming application which reads data from a kafka stream and processes it. I am running the following.

```
val schema = new StructType()
      .add("InvoiceNo", LongType)
      .add("StockCode", LongType)
      .add("Description", StringType)
      .add("Quantity", ShortType)
      .add("InvoiceDate", StringType)
      .add("UnitPrice", DoubleType)
      .add("CustomerID", IntegerType)
      .add("Country", StringType)


    val df = spark.readStream.
      format("kafka").
      option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", conf.get("spark.kafka_bootstrap_servers")).
      option("subscribe", "webserver").
      option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL").
      option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN").
      option("kafka.ssl.protocol", "TLSv1.2").
      option("kafka.ssl.enabled.protocols", "TLSv1.2").
      option("failOnDataLoss", "false").
      load()
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: CSV data source does not support binary data type.
```

The csv I am giving in the stream is

```
536365,85123A,WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER,6,01/12/10 8:26,2.55,17850,United Kingdom
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

`spark.readStream.format("kafka")` always reads data as binary, not as a String.

> Values are always deserialized as byte arrays with ByteArrayDeserializer. Use DataFrame operations to explicitly deserialize the values
>     - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

It's not clear where you used `.csv()` or `schema` variable.

You can see in the [docs how it casts keys and values to strings](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-streaming-queries)

Comment: How do I enforce the schema?

Comment: Well, first you'd have to cast the kafka message to at least a string. I have no experience with streaming CSV because that's just a poor format to put into Kafka. Json or Avro works best. For example https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html

Comment: You might want to see this though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903276/spark-streaming-read-csv-string-from-kafka-write-to-parquet